# cron job with error php Warning - Undefined property: CRM_Core_DAO::$contribution_id

Tags: php, cron-job

I'm curing a Joomla instance CiviCRM. Just updated from Joomla 3 to joomla 4.4.1 with CiviCRM 5.68.1. 
Updated too the server debian version from 11 to 12. 
configured cron task with cv version v0.3.48

/opt/cv api job.execute --user=XXXX --quiet --cwd=/var/www/html/XXXX/htdocs

Got this message repeated multiple times :

> [PHP Warning] Undefined property: CRM_Core_DAO::$contribution_id at /var/www/html/XXXX/htdocs/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Contact/BAO/Query.php:4664

How can I get rid of this error ?

Comment: Just FYI you're going to see hundreds of various types of php warnings throughout civi if you're using php 8. Civi "works" with php 8, and is recommended, but still has lots of these warnings. This particular one might be hard to fix because it would require investigating which job and which record is causing it. It could be bad data, or a bad saved search, or something else.

Comment: Thanks for this warning ;)
So I presume I will ignore crontab messages on a daily basis.